# Can we decrease the value of $g$ (gravitational pull) without gaining height?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, earth, planets, centrifugal-force

The value of $g$ on earth surface is $9.8\ \text{m/s}^2$ and when we gain height, then the value of $g$ decreases.  Pilots experience same phenomena in air, but can we decrease the value of $g$ by staying on ground?

Comment: In a spherical approximation, the value of $g$ increases linearly with distance from the center of the earth.  So, you could decrease the $g$ you experience by digging deep into the earth as well, albeit only slightly.  Also, the $g$ you experience is different at different latitudes.  At the equator, the rotational speed of the earth works to decrease the value of $g$ slightly

Comment: ok,i explain in clear way...suppose i am plying a jet game but i want that less gravity or  variable pressure with the increasing or decreasing height of my plane in game.now is it possible to make the value of gravity variable?

Comment: Your comment makes no sense.  $F_{gravity} = \frac{GMm}{r^2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Can we decrease the value of g (gravitational pull) without gaining height?**

No.

---

Implicit in your question is that:

- You have a fixed position on the surface of the planet Earth.
- You do not have the ability to move planet-sized masses around.
- You want to decrease the gravitational pull by more than could be achieved by:

  - levelling nearby mountains or by
  - transporting yourself to another place on the Earth's surface (e.g. from equator to pole).

Note that, for short periods of time, you can simulate the effect of reduced gravity by introducing other accellerations. This is easier [inside an actual aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_gravity_aircraft) - but that may defeat the purpose of your question. Maybe you could arrange something using a rocket sled and a railway track over a suitably re-contoured mountain?

Answer (score 2):

The effective value of $g$ decreases as you move away from Earth's surface because of [Newton's Shell Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem).  The decrease goes like the square of the distance from the center of the Earth, but like all smooth functions you can approximate it as a linear decrease over small changes in height.  From sea level to the top of the atmosphere counts as a "small" change in height for these purposes (100 km / 6000 km = 2% of total, for a 4%-ish change in the strength of gravity between sea level and space).

tmwilson claims in a comment that $g$ decreases as you tunnel into the Earth.  This would be true if the Earth were a sphere of *uniform* density, also due to the shell theorem, since there is zero gravitational force on the *inside* of a spherical shell and zero gravitational force at the exact center of the Earth.  However the Earth is a sphere which is denser at the core than at the surface, which makes the question more complicated.

You clarify in a comment that you're interested in changing $g$ with altitude; that goes only one way, with gravity getting weaker at high altitude.

Comment: @ rob thanks for help,,In my 1st comment i am saying that i want to change gravity with the change of altitude of my plane IN GAME...in short i wanted to say that i am plying game in a closed cabin same like cockpit and what i want is to introduce pressure and gravity so that the plying person can play the game like REAL...